# Compute anomaly temperature trends in R

Tags: r, time-series, anomaly-detection, climate

I would like to perform an anomaly temperature trends analysis in R. I have temperature data from 1901 to 2012. My idea to compute anomaly temperature trends was as follows: 
1. Compute temperature means per month over this time period
2. Subtract temperature means from actual data, to get an anomaly in temperature per month. 
3. Perform a linear regression on this anomaly values to get the anomaly temperature trends.

However, I am not quite sure about the approach. Anyone has done this before and could give me some hints?

Comment: Could you explain what an "anomaly temperature trend" is intended to be?  Only then could we ascertain whether your proposed approach may be appropriate for analyzing it.

Comment: It is done every day by scientists to remove the linear trend before calculating correlations for example.